# Protractor - Add second driver with different Selenium address

Tags: selenium, webdriver, protractor

I would like to test my website from second device , using Selenium server launched on it.

How to create in test second instance of browser with different Selenium address ?

I saw only solutions with local browsers

Comment: You would need a VM if you don't have the device.

Comment: I have device , it is not a problem. I would like to simply inside one 'it' check something on browser from DEVICE1 and then create new drive instance, with seleniumAddress pointing to DEVICE2 and chech something there.